# tkinter radiobutton: is it possible to toggle value & color with only 1 button

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, toggle

I know that radiobuttons is a frequent topic: I have spent several hours trying to find an example solution, but no luck.  Maybe I missed it.  Anyway, I would like to have a single radio button that I press to toggle between 0 and 1 and that also changes color from green (value = 0, mute OFF) to red (value = 1, Mute ON).  The following is my code for a two button solution (no color change):

```
from tkinter import *  # Python 3

def Set_Mute(value):
    Mute = (value)
    if Mute > 0:
        print ("Mute is On", Mute)
    if Mute == 0:
        print ("Mute is Off", Mute)
    return

root = Tk()
root.title("Fidelity Science Audio Control GUI")
root.geometry("500x500")

Radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Mute On", indicatoron=0,
                selectcolor="light blue", command=lambda: Set_Mute(1))
Radiobutton1.grid(row=10, column=30)

Radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Mute Off", indicatoron=0,
                selectcolor="light blue", command=lambda: Set_Mute(0))
Radiobutton2.grid(row=10, column=40)

root.mainloop()
```

If there is a better widget to use, please let me know.  Thank you. Patrick

Comment: it is work for [Checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) for this.

You can assign function which will change colors - but on Linux it changes colors correctly only when you have `indicatoron=True` (default value).

[image] [image]

```
import tkinter as tk

def change():
    #print(selected.get())

    if selected.get():
        cb['text'] = 'Mute OFF'
        cb['bg'] = 'red'
        cb['activebackground'] = 'red'
        #cb['highlightbackground'] = 'red'
    else:        
        cb['text'] = 'Mute ON'
        cb['bg'] = 'green'
        cb['activebackground'] = 'green'
        #cb['highlightbackground'] = 'green'

root = tk.Tk()

selected = tk.BooleanVar()

cb = tk.Checkbutton(root,
                    text="Mute ON",
                    bg='green',
                    activebackground='green',
                    variable=selected,
                    #indicatoron=False,
                    command=change)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

But you can also use [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) to do the same.

You need only change value in variable when you press button to have information if it is `ON` or `OFF`.

[image] [image]

```
import tkinter as tk

def change():
    #change value
    selected.set(not selected.get())
    #print(selected.get())

    if selected.get():
        btn['text'] = 'Mute OFF'
        btn['bg'] = 'red'
        btn['activebackground'] = 'red'
    else:        
        btn['text'] = 'Mute ON'
        btn['bg'] = 'green'
        btn['activebackground'] = 'green'

root = tk.Tk()

selected = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)

btn = tk.Button(root,
                    text="Mute ON",
                    bg='green',
                    activebackground='green',
                    command=change)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons are not the best choice for this idea (they are intended for multiple use), but they change colour already with `indicatoron`, as illustrated:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

v = IntVar()
button1 = Radiobutton(root, indicatoron=0, text="One", variable=v, font='Verdana, 10', value=0)
button2 = Radiobutton(root, indicatoron=0, text="Two", variable=v, font='Verdana, 10', value=1)
button3 = Radiobutton(root, indicatoron=0, text="Three", variable=v, font='Verdana, 10', value=2)
button1.pack(); button2.pack(); button3.pack()
mainloop()
```

This produces:

[image: result]

As you can see, the background of the button changes to white; colors are unsupported with the use of `indicatoron`. (green and red are unavailable with this)

I suggest you look at the [checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) widget.